# Retrieving Multiple INDEX_STATS from Several Tables

Tags: sql, oracle, tree

How can I retrieve the height of B+ tree index of several tables. Other indexes such as the number of leaf blocks of the tree. How do I use the INDEX_STATS to a targeted set of tables? Such as HEIGHT, LF_BLKS...

Table examples such as Emp, Salary, Ranking

Answer (score 1):

You can more easily view basic index statistics with data dictionary views such as `ALL_INDEXES`:

```
select owner, table_name, index_name, blevel, leaf_blocks
from all_indexes
where table_name in ('EMP', 'SALARY', 'RANKING')
order by owner, table_name, index_name;
```

`INDEX_STATS` only contains information gathered from the last `ANALYZE INDEX...` operation, and `ALL_INDEXES` contains all the latest statistics for each index you have access to. But if your statistics are not up to date, you may need to gather them like this:

```
begin
    dbms_stats.gather_index_stats(user, 'EMP_IDX');
end;
/
```